# CountDownTimer doesn't count down by the specified intervals

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdown

I'm trying to build a count-down timer function in my app, however, it doesn't run as expected.

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(100, 10) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long l) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onTick: " + l);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                
                            }
                        }.start();
```

My expectations are that it would count down gradually from 100,90,80...till 0

Although the output timer is showing quite random times (34 then 18 then 8..etc).
How can I achieve what I want?

It's difficult to explain the exact idea I'm trying to achieve but basically, I'm using touch listeners to hover over an item which in turn loads a few other items in the view. For some reason, there should be an intentional delay of around 100ms before these items could be displayed. I'm trying to build a progress bar that tells the user that something is loading rather than giving the impression that the screen is just stuck. I hope that helps to give a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: It seems like `CountDownTimer` uses `Handler` under the hood. It may just not be precise enough. You could try other or lower level APIs, maybe take a look at `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: What task you are suppose to do in millisecond interval ?

Comment: This is signature of CountDownTimer constructor :  public CountDownTimer (long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval). Why did you put 100 ms as first argument? You should put something like this new CountDownTimer(100000 ,1000) if you want to achieve counting like 100,99,...

Comment: I've updated the question with my idea and what I want to achieve